# Spring REST Docs - parts not documented:

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-rest, spring-restdocs

I have a springBoot 2.1.9.RELEASE application that uses Spring REST Docs.

I have this payload

```
{
  "hostel" : [ {
    "bookingHostelIdentifier" : {
      "internalMasterIdentifier" : {
        "id" : "987654321"
      }
    }
  }, {
    "bookingHostelIdentifier" : {
      "customerIdentifier" : {
        "id" : "23456789"
      }
    }
  }, {
    "bookingHostelIdentifier" : {
      "internalMasterIdentifier" : {
        "id" : "87654321"
      }
    }
  } ]
}
```

which I documented like this

```
fieldWithPath("hostel[]").description("The list of hostels"),
fieldWithPath("hostel[].name").description("The list of hostels"),
fieldWithPath("hostel[].bookingHostelIdentifier").description("The list of hostels"),
fieldWithPath("hostel[].bookingHostelIdentifier.internalMasterIdentifier.id").description("The list of hostels"),
fieldWithPath("hostel[].bookingHostelIdentifier.customerIdentifier.id").description("The list of hostels")
```

but I got this Exception

```
org.springframework.restdocs.snippet.SnippetException: 
Fields with the following paths were not found in the payload: 
[hostel[].bookingHostelIdentifier.internalMasterIdentifier.id, hostel[].bookingHostelIdentifier.customerIdentifier.id]
```

Comment: What if you add internalMasterIdentifier and to every entity ? in payload (i dont care if it is valid or not, just want to know will that work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `internalMasterIdentifier` and the `customerIdentifier` fields are not always present in a `bookingHostelIdentifier`, you should mark those fields or the `id` fields that are nested beneath them as optional.

```
fieldWithPath("hostel[].bookingHostelIdentifier.internalMasterIdentifier.id").optional().description("The list of hostels"),
fieldWithPath("hostel[].bookingHostelIdentifier.customerIdentifier.id").optional().description("The list of hostels")
```